# iFrame in DIV with height/width 100%

Tags: html, css, iframe

I would like to use an iFrame in the Content-DIV to avoid loading the navigation all the time.

Is it possible to include an iFrame there whichs is fullheight/fullwidth inside the second DIV?

```
<div style="position:fixed;width:190px;height:1500px;background:#951b24;float:left;z-index:1000;padding:25px>

Navigation

</div>

<div style="position:absolute;top:25px;left:265px;width:auto;height:auto">
Content
</div>
```

Comment: Possible, yes; what you want, probably not. An iframe is a completely separate document. If you want to reduce code duplication, a better solution would be to use server side rendering and include the navigation file into each page. If you want to prevent page reloading on navigation you need to look into single page web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean that?

```html
<div style="position:fixed;width:190px;height:1500px;background:#951b24;float:left;z-index:1000;padding:25px">

Navigation

</div>

<div style="position:absolute;top:25px;left:265px;width:calc(100% - 265px);height:100%;">
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yfoY53QXEnI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```